# Assign variable based on if statements in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's the following pseudo code I'm achieving:

```
if {./jobtype eq 1} jobbackgroundcolor='#ffffff';
if {./jobtype eq 2} jobbackgroundcolor='#000000';
if {./jobtype eq 3} jobbackgroundcolor='#ababab';
if {./jobtype eq 4} jobbackgroundcolor='#eac123';
if {./jobtype eq 5} jobbackgroundcolor='#eacddd';
```

I don't know how to set the jobbackgroundcolor to a variable so I can essentially do this:

```
<a href="" style="background-color:{$jobbackgroundcolor}"></a>
```

Of course the code is pseudo code so any concrete implementations would be great.

Comment: I believe you are looking for `xsl:choose`. Please post an example of the input and the expected output, if you want a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### XSLT 2.0 solution

**Given this input XML**

```
<jobtype>3</jobtype>
```

**this XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version='1.0' xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform'>
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="jt" select="number(jobtype)"/>
    <a>
      <xsl:if test="$jt = (1 to 5)">
        <xsl:attribute name="style"
                       select="concat('background-color:',
                               ('#ffffff','#000000','#ababab','#eac123','#eacddd')[$jt])"/>
      </xsl:if>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**will output this XML**

```
<a style="background-color:#ababab"/>
```

**as requested.**